# Change the color of a button if at least one option is chosen from a <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select with several options and a gray button that pretends to be disabled. I want that if at least one option is chosen, the button will change color.

And this is my function, but I can't make it change the color of the button

```js
var options = document.getElementById('months').selectedOptions;
var value = Array.from(options).map(({
  value
}) => value);
if (value.length > 0) {
  let element = document.getElementById("btn_next");
  element.classList.remove("color");
  element.classList.add("color2");
}
```

```css
.color {
  background: gray;
}

.color2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="months" name="months" multiple>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Fabruary">Fabruary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btn_next" type="button" class="color" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to put the code in an event listener so it runs when the user changes the selection. You're running it when the page first loads, so the user hasn't had a chance to select anything.

Comment: There's no need for the `value` array. If you want to know if any options are selected, just get the length of `selectedOptions`. If it's non-zero then some options were selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to check the selected options after each change. To simplify the code, you can just toggle a disabled class instead of handling two classes.

```js
const btnNext = document.getElementById("btn_next");
document.getElementById("months").addEventListener("change", e => {
  btnNext.classList.toggle('disabled', !e.target.selectedOptions.length);
});
```

```css
#btn_next {
  background: orange;
}
#btn_next.disabled {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<select id="months" name="months" multiple>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Fabruary">Fabruary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<input id="btn_next" type="button" class="disabled" value="NEXT">
```

This can also be done with only CSS using the [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```css
#btn_next {
  background: grey;
}
#months:has(:checked) + #btn_next {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<select id="months" name="months" multiple>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Fabruary">Fabruary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<input id="btn_next" type="button" value="NEXT">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to the change event on the select field to toggle class on the button. Apply a callback to onchange event, for instance

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn_next");
document.getElementById('months').onchange = function(e) {
  const value = this.selectedOptions;
  if (value.length > 0) {
    button.classList.remove("color");
    button.classList.add("color2");
  }
};
```

```css
.color {
  background: gray;
}

.color2 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="months" name="months" multiple>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="Fabruary">Fabruary</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btn_next" type="button" class="color" value="NEXT">
</form>
```